# GNU Parallel: startup script on each node

Tags: gnu-parallel

Is there a way to run a startup (or teardown) script on each node when using GNU Parallel?

For example, I wish to distribute (and balance) many single-threaded tasks among many multi-core nodes (specifically using PBS to assign which nodes, from a shared HPC cluster). For each new node, it is necessary to run some set-up commands (e.g. loading environment modules) once-off before running tasks.

Comment: Should I simply accept the inefficiency of making every individual task reload the environment modules?

Comment: Is there an alternative to GNU parallel? xargs -P is great on a single machine; is there another simple tool for balancing many trivially-parallisable tasks over multiple hosts?

Comment: Possibly `--env` of `env_parallel` has some similar effects?

Answer (score 1):

Can you use `--nonall`?

```
parallel --nonall --slf $PBS_NODEFILE setup.sh
```

This will not work if it is setting up environment. For that you could try:

```
env_parallel --record-env
[load the environment]
seq 100 | env_parallel --slf $PBS_NODEFILE --env _ echo do the job
```

Comment: you mean `-S $(cat $PBS_NODEFILE)` or `--sshlogin $PBS_NODEFILE` ?

Comment: Just realised cluster does not readily permit `ssh` between nodes (but changing the ssh command might otherwise be a way to get the effect I asked for). Not sure if possible to create a ssh-like command using pbsdsh. Is there an MPI version of parallel?

Comment: Sorry: `--slf $PBS_NODEFILE`.